# Right click and fingerprint reader not working

Tags: touchpad

I am trying out ElementaryOS (Odin) for the first time on my Asus Vivobook, but for some reason I can't right click on the touchpad, and also I see no option to log in using my touchpad's built in fingerprint reader. I am enjoying ElementaryOS so far, but these are "killer features" that I need if I am to use this operating system. Is there any way to get this working?

I've been around the block with Debian and Ubuntu earlier, but consider me a greenhorn.

Comment: In the default settings, you click by tapping the touchpad, not pressing it. I think you can change this in Settings → Mouse and Touchpad.